# Reputation change marked as new after refresh in apps

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app

Today I noticed that old reputation changes on achievements tab marked as new (blue background) after refreshing via pulling down.

iOS:

> [image: achievements iOS]

Android:

> [image: achievements Android]

Same behavior for iOS and Android apps. Because of this I believe that the problem in API.

Each refresh can mark different items in the list.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.0.2 (Build 15A421)

---

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (172342203b663)

Comment: Could it be related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301418/323179)?

Comment: @Laurel hardly. I have no problem with web, only apps affected.

Comment: Was just about to post this. Same problem. It keeps getting my hopes up :O Android 6.0.1, Samsung Note 4. Version 1.0.95

Comment: Yup I saw the unusual behaviour just few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this's not happening anymore. Worth noting that now I use iOS app version 1.6.6.2 from AppStore due to [lack of beta updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301986/339911). Android app version is still same as in bug report post.